# Workaround for run sp_rename from within a transaction on SAP/Sybase ASE (Error 17260)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I am trying call to `sp_rename` inside transaction (`BEGIN TRANSACTION`), but it shows this error message:

```
Can't run sp_rename from within a transaction., Error 17260, Procedure sp_rename, Line 78
```

The `sp_rename` code checks for any open transactions::

```
/*
** Running sp_rename inside a transaction would endanger the
** recoverability of the transaction/database. Disallow it.
** Do the @@trancount check before initializing any local variables,
** because "select" statement itself will start a transaction
** if chained mode is on.
*/
if @@trancount > 0
begin
    /*
    ** 17260, "Can't run %1! from within a transaction."
    */
    raiserror 17260, "sp_rename"
    return (1)
end
else
begin
    set chained off
end
```

I don't understand why these actions are a danger....

Additionally, I need a way to call this stored procedure within the transaction and then rollback this action.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **1)** users updating systems table, while in a transaction, is typically frowned upon however **2)** several system procs (including `sp_rename`) **do** perform such actions so **3)** I'm not sure why this particular proc has been coded explicitly to disable a user-initiated transactions; would likely need to raise the question with tech support (who would likely need to forward to ASE engineering) for a detailed explanation; as for a workaround ... you could try a modified version of `sp_rename` (not recommended for a production environment) though at that point you'd be on your own ...

Comment: ... otherwise it may help if you provide a scenario where you foresee the need to run `sp_rename` inside a user-defined txn

Comment: I am building a unit testing framework for sybase/ase code. 
For my case, each test is a stored procedure. These tests should have calls from different sps with functionalities of the framework, such as creating fake tables among others.

Comment: Each test is executed inside a transaction that makes sure to leave everything to the initial state when the test is finished (including the renaming of some table with the fake table program). When I try to run a test to create a fake table the error occurs because of the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

`ASE` isn't really designed for rolling back schema changes (as you're seeing).

If you want a means of testing your 'framework functionality' consider:

- create a new `test` db
- run your scripts against this `test` db
- when done just drop the `test` db; an alternative would be to run a series of `drop` commands to 'undo' all the schema changes

New databases are initially created as a copy of the `model` database so you could go so far as to install some base components in the `model` database but keep in mind the `model database` (and its contents) are used when creating all new databases (eg, all temp dbs when starting `ASE`), so don't add anything to the `model` database that you wouldn't want showing up in any new databases (outside your 'framework functionality' testing).

What you're proposing doesn't sound much different than what I've seen developers regularly do when testing a new 'release':

- load a copy of the prod db
- apply release package against said db
- rinse/repeat until release package completes successfully
- key being to start with a newly loaded (or created) database

A variation on the above:

- create a new `test` db
- add base components as needed
- dump/save a copy of the `test` db
- run your tests
- when you want to run your test again then load that dump/saved copy back into the `test` db, then run tests again
- basically same thing as loading copy of prod db but in this case you load a copy of your base `test` db